# Migrating code to 10.1 and recycled search

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, extensions

I am migrating 9.3 Desktop extension to 10.1

I am getting this bug when I am trying to update a row in the geodatabase

"Cannot call Store on a recycled row while editing"

And seems the reason is, I am doing recyclable search like this

eatCursor = featLayer.Search(spatialFilter, true);

So, I changed it to false recyclable.
And it worked.

But my question is why 10.1 is not able to update recycled row, where 9.3 was able to?
what the reason of this change?
Is there any reason 10.1 disabled this feature?

Comment: "Feature"? More like a bug with unintended benefits :)

Comment: Do you mean that 9.3 had a bug?

Comment: That is my assumption, yes.